# Error in JUnit testing of service

Tags: android, junit

Code:

```
public class Testprogdi extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {

    public Testprogdi(String pkg, Class activityClass) {
        super(pkg, activityClass);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    Context mContext;

    Registration reg = new Registration();

    public void setUp(){
        try {
            super.setUp();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mContext = this.getInstrumentation().getContext();
    }   

    public void test(){
        Assert.assertNotNull(reg.pass_url());}
    public void test1(){
        Assert.assertTrue(reg.pass_url().startsWith("www"));}
    public void test2(){
        Assert.assertTrue(reg.pass_url().startsWith("http"));
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Class com.android.deviceintelligence.test.Testprogdi has no public constructor TestCase(String name) or TestCase()
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1448)`
```

I am getting the same error for all my test classes.

Comment: I honestly don't know anything about `junit test cases` but I think as your exceptions suggest, you should probably declare `public constructor` by name `TestCase(String name)` or `TestCase()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A TestCase should have a no-arg public constructor or a constructor with a single String parameter.

You should delete your public Testprogdi(String pkg, Class activityClass) constructor and do any kind of initialization in the setUp() method or add

```
public Testprogdi() {}
```

or

```
public Testprogdi(String name) {
    // initialization 
}
```

Btw, your test would be more maintainable if you do some other changes (not related to the first problem):

Give more meaningful names to your test methods.

There is no need to catch (Exception e) in the setUp().

I don´t see how test1() and test2() can both pass.

Comment: if it's the right solution you should accept it by hitting the check mark next on the top left side of his answer. that way the community knows what is the correct solution when in your particular situation

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse gives you constructor templates like:

```
public Testprogdi(String pkg, Class<progdi> activityClass) {
    super(pkg, activityClass);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

or:

```
public Testprogdi(Class<progdi> activityClass) {
    super(activityClass);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

progdi is the name of your Activity Class. But as the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html) says the contsructor should be something like this:

```
public Testprogdi() {
    super("com.progdi", progdi.class);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

and you forget the parameter  here:

```
public class Testprogdi extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<progdi> {}
```